# Simple random function in an interval

Tags: javascript, random

It doesn't give me a value r in the given range? Why?

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var x = window.prompt("minimo");
var y = window.prompt("maximo");
var r = getRandomIntInclusive(x,y);

console.log(r);
```

edit: This function has been taken from [a link of dev mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
Thank you

Comment: What are your inputs being sent as to the random function? Use your console debugger to see what the values are before and after the function gets them.

Comment: @mariocatch just Integers

Comment: No, that's not true. I'm telling you to test it through your debugger because you need to see why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prompt` returns a string, you need to parse those strings into integers:

```js
 function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }
 var x = parseInt(window.prompt("minimo"), 10);
 var y = parseInt(window.prompt("maximo"), 10);
 var r = getRandomIntInclusive(x, y);
 console.log(r);
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem!

Comment: console.log("biggest of three"); var x = window.prompt("enter a number"); var y = window.prompt("enter b number"); var z = window.prompt("enter c number"); if (x>=y && x>=z){  console.log(x+" is the biggest"); } else if (y>=z && y>=x){  console.log(y+" is the biggest"); }  else if (z>=x && z>=y){  console.log(z+" is the biggest"); } this works though

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, some things will work because JS auto-casts string into integers in certain cases, but it's always better to do the casting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`window.prompt` is returning a string, so when you add min ( `+ min` ), you get string concatenation instead of addition. A simple solution is to convert the result of `window.prompt` to a number:

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var x = parseInt( prompt("minimo"), 10 );
var y = parseInt( prompt("maximo"), 10 );
var r = getRandomIntInclusive(x,y);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `parseInit()` to convert string to integer

```js
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var x = window.prompt("minimo");
var y = window.prompt("maximo");
var r = getRandomIntInclusive(parseInt(x),parseInt(y));

alert(r);
```

Comment: No. Not a link - the actual code. If jsfiddle breaks your answer is useless. As it it you might want to spend a bit of your answer explaining _what_ `parseInt` actually does to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that javascript is not treating the values as numbers, and is instead treating them as strings.

The below code should **get you started** fixing this problem, however note that it can have errors if you pass in bad values:

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = parseFloat(min);
  max = parseFloat(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a5fng2h6/

Answer (score -1):

Try : min + Math.floor( Math.random()*max)

Comment: This will not solve the OP's strings-instead-of-numbers problem; the `+` in your answer is still concatenation instead of addition.